# Search the SP's with the Keyword

Tags: sql, stored-procedures

Any mechanism to find whether all the Store Procedure has same keyword..

for example i have a test DB which is having 100 Store Procedure. i want to find which Store Procedure is using the `Employee Cadre` to modify the related Store Procedure's

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do it like this:

```
SELECT OBJECT_NAME(id) 
    FROM syscomments 
    WHERE [text] LIKE '%youtext%' 
    AND OBJECTPROPERTY(id, 'IsProcedure') = 1 
    GROUP BY OBJECT_NAME(id)
```

Answer (score 0):

It would help to know what DBMS you are talking about. This is not a standard SQL question, as suggested by the SQL tag and your text. Every DBMS has different system tables and different ways to implement / represent stored procedures.